# ssi an error occurred while processing this directive

Tags: windows, apache, ssi, shtml

I get the following error in my shtml files

```
[an error occurred while processing this directive]
```

This error does not happen when including another file, it happens when I do if expressions like:

```
<!--#if expr="$QUERY_STRING = open-updates" --> open<!--#endif -->
```

I am running this dev environment on a windows machine using xampp

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tab the code out so if wasnt displayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had to put the following directive in my httpd.conf

```
SSILegacyExprParser on
```

The shtml files I am using came originally from a legacy apache server (1.X)